# how can I delete a specific item from dropdown field in react

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, multi-select, react-select

Previously I had one dropdown field for whitelist where user could select options from dropdown. Whatever user select from the list, it shows in the field with a remove icon. By clicking remove icon in front of the each items user could simply remove the specific item from the field. It looks like this:
[image]

For this feature code looks like this:

```
protected getRenderItemFunc = () => {
        return (arg: OptionValue) => {
            const label = arg.label
            const removeItem = (e: any) => {
                this.removeItem(e, arg)
            }
            return (
                <div className="simple-value">
                    <span>{label}</span>
                    <span
                        onClick={removeItem}
                        onMouseDown={this.stopEventPropagation}
                        className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                    >
                        {' '}
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

public render() {
        return (
                <h3 className="h4">White list</h3>

                <Row>
                    <Col md={3} sm={5} xs={6}>
                        <MultiSelect
                            placeholder="Select groups"
                            values={this.state.private_marketplace_groups}
                            options={this.state.private_marketplace_suggestions}
                            onValuesChange={(values: any) => this.privateMarketplaceOnChange(values)}
                            theme="bootstrap3"
                            className="w-100p"
                            renderValue={this.getRenderItemFunc()}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
)}
```

The above code simply works fine.
Now I want to add similar dropdown feature which is called **black list** which means one user can black listed other users. Like this:

[image]

Here is the code I have added for this:

```
<h3 className="h4">Black list</h3>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={3} sm={5} xs={6}>
                        <MultiSelect
                            placeholder="Select groups"
                            values={this.state.blacklist_groups}
                            options={this.state.private_marketplace_suggestions}
                            onValuesChange={(values: any) => this.blackListOnChange(values)}
                            theme="bootstrap3"
                            className="w-100p"
                            renderValue={this.getRenderItemFunc()}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
```

Here, I am using the same function `this.getRenderItemFunc()` for both white list and black list to remove a specific item. Removing a specific item simply works fine for white list but removing specific item is not working for black list. Could any one tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the `this. blackListOnChange` function as well?

Comment: I managed to make it working. ```this.removeItem(e, arg)```  is a wrong function name in the getRenderItemFunc()